# Qiskit TwoQubitBasisDecomposer - how to properly decompose gates?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I'm new with Qiskit and I'm struggling with creating my own controlled gates. I'm trying to create a ZYZ decomposition of a controlled unitary gate I created. I'm trying to use the method `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer`. Here is a piece of my code

```
U = Operator([[a,b],[c,d]]) #forms an unitary matrix

ucirc = QuantumCircuit(1)
ucirc.unitary(U,0)

c_ucirc = ucirc.control()

Ug = c_ucirc.to_gate()
UgZYZ = TwoQubitBasisDecomposer(Ug, euler_basis="ZYZ")
print(UgZYZ.basis)
```

When printing the basis Qiskit returns  the equivalent two-qubit decomposed gate

[image]

However, I don't know how to actually get the gate itself to insert on other algorithms. How can I proceed? All methods within `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer` ask for a target. What is such a target?

Answer (score 1):

The class `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer` decomposes 2-qubit unitaries using the minimum number of a 2-qubit basis gate of your choice. You pass this basis gate to the class constructor.
In your code snippet, `Ug` is the basis gate that will be used to decompose the other unitaries.

Given a 2-qubit unitary `G`, you can decompose it as follows. Note that, `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer` implements `__call__` so we can call its instance as a function.

```
# Here, we create a random 2-qubit unitary:
from qiskit.quantum_info.random import random_unitary
G = random_unitary(4).data

# Now, we decompose it using your decomposer:
circ = UgZYZ(G)
circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did help me.